# Maximum amount of money allowed when immigrating into the U. S

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, money

My  husband and I will be travelling to the U.S. as immigrants. Is  there a limit in bringing in  $ cash since we are  migrating  to the U.S.? Or it is the same amount ($10, 000)  as for tourist?  If so, is it $10, 000 - each for me and my husband?

Comment: I wonder if this question might be better suited to [expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), as it's about moving to a new country?

Answer (score 5):

There is no limit on bringing money with you - neither for tourists, nor for immigrants.

However, you will have to *declare* the money that you bring to the us. See [this page by the US Customs & Border protection](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195/kw/declare%20money/related/1/suggested/1) for details. The page also states that the threshold for the obligation to *declare* it is USD 10k *per family travelling together*.

Comment: Also note that it's $10k in currency or "negotiable instruments", with a list of what counts. So don't think you can bring 10k cash plus a pile of other stuff and not have to report. That said, I don't think much happens to you if you do declare it,

Answer (score 2):

This can be tricky situation. Anything more than 10k needs to be declared and will likely result in a lengthy conversation with the customs agent. During this conversation you will  be asked what your intentions are: what do you want to do with the money, and what are you thoughts about immigration. The last question needs to be answered very carefully or you may be declined entry. The right answer depends on what your actual intentions are and how far along you are in the process (if applicable). I would strongly recommend consulting an immigration professional on this

Although it's tempting to just hide it in the diapers, it is  NOT a good idea to try smuggling it in. Any large cash transaction in the US gets reported to the IRS or treasury anyway, so there is a high likelihood that someone will find out and than you are in serious trouble.

Example: we brought in a decent amount of cash to buy a car. We declared it properly at entry (and endured the examination). When buying the car using the cash, the dealer had to report the cash transaction including the source of the money. Since we had declared it properly, we just said "brought in from different country". Otherwise that would have been difficult.

Comment: It sounds to me as if the OP has the necessary immigration authorization already.

Comment: @Andrew: true but this process can takes many steps, e.g. "filed for H1B", "H1B holder", "filed for Green Card", "green Card approved" "advanced parole", "green card holder". The right answer depends on what step you are currently in